# Xcode: Increment build number

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, ios10, agvtool

We use a script that creates a time stamp and replaces the apps build number.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Update Build Number to Timestamp"
echo "--------------------------------"
# fail on error
set -e
agvtool new-version -all $(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
```

This changes the build number to something like this: `201703241425`.

We introduced an in-house framework to our Project.

The command above also replaces the frameworks `Build` number and `Current Library Version`.  However, the builds fail with the following error:

```
▸ Linking In-HouseFrameworkLayer

❌  ld: malformed 64-bit a.b.c.d.e version number: 201703241425
❌  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

[image]

When I change the format for the framework's `Build` number, `Current Library Version` to 1.0.0 and do a build **without** using the script above, the builds are successful.

Question: How can I change the `Build` number **ONLY** for the app, but **NOT** the framework `Current Library Version` number?

Answer (score 3):

Obviously the app uses `CFBundleVersion` + `$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)`; libraries/frameworks are supposed to use `(Current Library Version)` + `$(DYLIB_CURRENT_VERSION)`

**By default it is set to `$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)`, so this is what you'll need to change to the `$(DYLIB_CURRENT_VERSION)` string.**

> **Important**: For macOS apps, build numbers must monotonically increase even across different versions. In other words, for macOS
>   apps you cannot use the same build numbers again in different release
>   trains. iOS apps have no such restriction and you can re-use the same
>   build numbers again in different release trains.

<sub>The value for a version number or build number must consist only of '.'s and numbers and must begin and end with a number. Each integer value separated by a period is a component of the version. The maximum number of characters in your version number or in your build number cannot exceed eighteen characters in total.</sub>

**iOS** 
 version numbers and build numbers may have three or more components, but the maximum size of the entire version number or build number must not exceed eighteen characters.

**macOS** apps are somewhat more restrictive than `iOS` apps. For `macOS` apps there is a limit of three components separated by periods and there may not be any more than three components.

↳ [Version Numbers and Build Numbers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2420/_index.html)

↳ [Automating Version and Build Numbers Using agvtool](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1827/_index.html)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer.  Inside the framework build settings, I do not see a key for `DYLIB_CURRENT_VERSION`.  Am I looking in the right place?

Comment: When I search the project, it shows up.  When I tap on it, it appears as `Current Library Version`, and the value is `20170324162615`.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't have a key for `CFBundleVersion`.  All and Combined are selected.

Comment: In the plist for my framework, I do see `Bundle version` and there it says `1.0`.  When I run the command `agvtool new-version -all $(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)` it changed to `20170324164011`.  Also, I do not have a `$(DYLIB_CURRENT_VERSION)` in project.

Comment: Is there a way to change `DYLIB_CURRENT_VERSION` with agvtools?

Comment: When I run the following command: `agvtool new-version -all $(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S` all the versions are changed to this format: `20170324164011`

Comment: It's `Current Library Version` and `Current Project Version`

Comment: I would like to timestamp the build number -- not sure how else to do it.

Comment: Yes, but what is the actual `<key>` in the XML .plist?

Comment: It's `<key>CFBundleVersion</key>`

Comment: Yep, as I thought, so you will want to set  the `$(DYLIB_CURRENT_VERSION)` for that in the settings, and then have your date or whichever string go to that variable. (eg. `DYLIB_CURRENT_VERSION = 20170324164011`).

Comment: How do I change that with with a script?  agvtools?

Comment: Sorry, also where do I add `DYLIB_CURRENT_VERSION = 20170324164011`?  in the Framework plist? or Build Settings?

Comment: @user1107173: There are multiple ways you can do it. One easy way is by adding it in your Frameworks `Build Settings` under`Linking` (eg. Setting: `Current Library Version` Value: `20170324164011`).

Comment: That's what the script does, but I get an error: `ld: malformed 64-bit a.b.c.d.e version number: 201703241425`

Comment: What is the actual version number?

Comment: I have two options when I type `version number` under Build Settings of my framework.  `Compatibility Version` is set to `1`.  The other is `Current Library Version` which is set to `201703241425`

Answer (score 3):

Let's do this in Apple's own way.
It will increase the build number after each successful build

I will guide you through 5 images, just go through it.

1. Select 'Edit Scheme...' from the dropdown, when you select your Project name located in right side to the Stop_build_button.
   [Check First Step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJBQT.png)
2. From leftSide menu expand the 'Build' option and select 'Post-actions'
   [Check Second Step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNDLw.png)
3. Here you can add your desired Codes(Scripts) you want to execute after successful build of your program. It is the place where we have to add a little amount of code to make our automation work perfectly. >> 1. select the 'add (+)' button from leftSide corner to add new script file >> 2. Now from the drop down select 'New Run Script Action'
   [Check Third Step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nUm6.png)
4. It has 3 fields >> 1. shell is already assigned for you >> 2. now for 'Provide you build settings from' Select your Project Name. >> 3. Theres a big field to add your Script, just copy and past this code there : [Check Fourth Step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2a7h.png)

   PLIST="${PROJECT_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_FILE}"
   PLB=/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy
   LAST_NUMBER=$($PLB -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "$PLIST")
   NEW_VERSION=$(($LAST_NUMBER + 1))
   $PLB -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $NEW_VERSION" "$PLIST"
5. After completing the 4th step just select 'Close' to close the window and we have to do the last step, Goto your 'plist.info' file in Project file menu and make sure 'Bundle Version' key under 'Key' Section most contain a Numeric Value [Check Fifth Step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsqZl.png)

Comment: Brillant! This should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep $(MARKETING_VERSION)
in Info.plist for CFBundleShortVersionString but
want to increase version after successful archive or build
then use following script
following script will increase app version like 1.0 to 2.0
but of-course that logic can be modified to lets say, add 1 more decimal to app version, or even increase minor or tiny/patch or major part of decimal, or even you can increase both version and build numbers, but you have to do that learning from other easily available scripts and modify accordingly

[Script to increase app version](https://gist.github.com/m-irfan/760a3d9ede6c76b38f5e5fd748f3e315)