# Fastlane increase build number throws Malformed 64-bit a.b.c.d.e version number

Tags: xcode, fastlane

I am trying to increment the build_number of my project with fastlane

```
new_build_number = Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M")
increment_build_number(
    build_number: new_build_number
)
```

But I am getting the following error:

**ld: malformed 64-bit a.b.c.d.e version number: 201901091627
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

This is because fastlane is increasing the Current Library version of my dynamic frameworks

[image]

(As it is said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43009669/xcode-increment-build-number), if I set $(DYLIB_CURRENT_VERSION) to the Current Library it works, but each time I execute fastlane it gets modified and fails again).

How can I make that Fastlane doesn't modify that Current Library version or  how can I increment the build number and make it works with dynamic frameworks?.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have fixed in the following way:

I have downloaded versioning plugin:

```
fastlane add_plugin versioning
```

And then I have increase the build number in the following way:

```
build_number = Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M")
  increment_build_number_in_plist(
    build_number: build_number,
    target: 'YourDesiredTarget'
  )
```

Like this you won't get increased the dynamic frameworks library version/build version and the error won't appear! :)

Answer (score 0):

`Time.now.to_i` returns the value of time as an integer number of **seconds** since the Epoch. Try to convert this value to minutes.

```
build_number = Time.now.to_i / 60
increment_build_number(
    build_number: build_number
)
```